# associate view with html button in django

Tags: django

i have a button and counter . by click the button counter shuold plus by one.
view code:

```
def details(request,id):
post=Post.objects.get(pk=id)
if request.POST['my_button_on_html']:
    post.counter +=1
    post.save()
return render(request,'details.html',{'post':post})
```

and html :

```
{{post.counter}}
<input type="submit" name="my_button_on_html" />
```

my problem is 'how  say to view : when i clicked on the button do somthing' 
how do that ?

html :

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{post.product_like}}
    <input type="submit" name="like" value='{{post.product_id}}' />
    </form>
```

Comment: What is it currently doing when you click `submit`? Is that button within a `<form>`?

Comment: submit is button  that increase my counter. yes.

Comment: Can you post your full html form?

Comment: <form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
 {{post.product_like}}
 <input type="submit" name="like" value='{{post.product_id}}' />
 </form>

Comment: You're using different names in your template and view...`if request.POST['like']:` and `post.product_like+=1`

Comment: i do that but your idea dosnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have done that myself :

views:

```
def details(request,id):
post=Post.objects.get(pk=id)
if(request.POST.get('button')):
    post.product_like +=1
    post.save()
return render(request,'details.html',{'post':post})
```

and html :

```
<form action="#" method="post">
{%csrf_token%}
<input type="submit"  value="{{post.product_like}}" name="button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wire the button to a view that adds one and returns the same page using the *onclick* attribute of button.

```
<button onclick.action={% url site:counter %} >Click me</button >
```

Or you could change the form's action to

```
{% url site:counter %}
```

However, this reloads the entire page every time you click, so I'm pretty sure that you wouldn't want to do that.

Comment: no isnt :D my question is : counter is vote  or like key . how increase that ?